# preg_replace for "Virginia" and "West Virginia"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm writing a script to convert an XML feed to HTML.  One part of the routine involves transforming raw State names to links with preg_replace.  It's mostly working fine, but I'm having problems with "Virginia" and "West Virginia."

```
<?php

$state_patterns = array(
    '/\balabama\b/i',
    '/\balaska\b/i',
    '/\barizona\b/i',
    '.....etc.....',
    '/\bvirginia\b/i',
    '/west virginia/i'
);

$state_replacements = array(
    '<a href="/path/to/alabama">Alabama</a>',
    '<a href="/path/to/alaska">Alaska</a>',
    '<a href="/path/to/arizona">Arizona</a>',
    '.....etc.....',
    '<a href="/path/to/virginia">Virginia</a>',
    '<a href="/path/to/west-virginia">West Virginia</a>'
);

$statelinks = preg_replace($state_patterns, $state_replacements, $xml_src);
```

Of course, the problem with this is that "Virginia" breaks "West Virginia".  The same breakage would occur for things like "Mexico" and "New Mexico."

What preg_replace pattern(s) could I use to overcome this conflict?

I have tried running "West Virginia" first and then "Virginia" afterwards. But that breaks too -- just in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind for the virginia regex. This will match "virginia" but not "west virginia"

```
\b(?<!west\s)virginia\b
```

Comment: That appears to be working perfectly for my situation.  Deep thanks man.